# How can determine how my partition is full even when it appears it is not?

Tags: partitioning, disk-space, freebsd

I have run "df -kh" on my FreeBSD box and I see that /var is near 100% full. It was over but I have trimmed what I can but there is less then 500MB total on the partition according to running "du -ksh *" while in /var. The /var partition itself is 6.8G and it now says it only has 18M free. It just does not add up.

I run the following command I do not find any culprits.

```
 find . -type f -size +2000 -exec ls -lh {} \; | awk '{ print $9 ": " $5 }'
```

I even drill down folder by folder using "du -ksh *" to identify the folders with lots of disk usage but I cannot find how it all adds up. I would like to compress, delete or move files in order to free up more space since the other partitions have space, but between df and du I cannot seem to find what is using all the disk space.

What else should I do to find the files and folders taking up all the space?

Comment: What file system is /var?  They don't all release delete file space immediately.  Also, all files will get rounded to the nearest block size so `ls` won't report disk space used - for lots of small files this can add up.  Do you have spare capacity to just create a bigger /var?

Comment: du should still show the amount of disk usage accurately even if ls does not on an individual folder. If I could identify where the disk usage is so heavy I could remedy it.

Comment: Sure - provided your blocks are 1K du should work with those parameters.  Any chance there is a `.*` file in the root of /var?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd run the following, so that you have a nice snapshot of all files to work with:

```
du -kx /var | sort -n | tee /var/tmp/du_results.out
```

... and then look at the last few hundred lines.

This will catch the size of all directories (to catch large numbers of small files), as well as catching ordinary large files.  Note that I'm *not* using `-h` (human-readable), so that the results are easily sorted numerically.  Note also that I'm not using `/var/*`, which would pick up anything mounted in `/var` as well.

The possible culprits include, in rough order of likelihood:

- Stale unlinked files.  Try what @not simon suggested (`lsof /var`).   `/var/tmp` is sometimes an obvious place to find these.  If you don't have `lsof` installed, you can use `fstat -f /var | sort -k 8 -n`, which doesn't show file names, but will at least show sizes (smallest to largest), inodes, and which process has the file open.
- Filesystem corruption.  Run`fsck` from single-user mode to check `/var`.
- Old files hidden under mount points.  If there are any mounts under `/var`, unmount them and then run your search/diagnostic again.  The safest way to do this is probably to boot in single-user mode, and just mount `/var` without mounting anything under it.

Differences in file size reporting can be due to the presence of sparse or compressed files.  You can use the `-A` option to `du` to work with apparent file size instead of disk usage, which might explain some discrepancies.  Put it in and then leave it out, and compare the results.  In my roughly 3.6Gb `/var` partition, results with `-A` were about 100Mb smaller.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered that you may have an unlinked file that is still open?  Try looking over the output of `lsof /var` to see if there are any unusually large files listed.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where a disk went away.  The mount point still existed, but for some reason files were being written to the directory *on the partition containing the mount point*.  This may not apply to your operating system, but booting a rescue system and perusing the partitions from there may reveal more.